# Can't get rid of compiler warnings for primitiveValue accessors in transient property getter impls

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I've implemented a transient property as below on one of the models in my app.  It is declared in the model design as a transient property with undefined type.

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSNumberFormatter *currencyFmt;
```

The current (warning-free) impl of this accessor is:

```
- (NSNumberFormatter *) currencyFmt
{
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"currencyFmt"];
    NSNumberFormatter *fmt = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"currencyFmt"];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"currencyFmt"];

    if (fmt == nil)
    {
        fmt = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
        [fmt setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
        [fmt setLocale:[self localeObject]];
        [self setPrimitiveValue:fmt forKey:@"currencyFmt"];
    }

    return fmt;
}
```

The call to `primitiveValueForKey:` is the problem here, since the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html) specifically warns against using this version of the primitive lookup:

> You are strongly encouraged to use the
>   dynamically-generated accessors rather
>   than using this method directly (for
>   example, primitiveName: instead of
>   primitiveValueForKey:@"name"). The
>   dynamic accessors are much more
>   efficient, and allow for compile-time
>   checking.

The problem is that if I try to use `primitiveCurrencyFmt` instead of `primitiveValueForKey:@"currencyFmt"`, I get a compiler warning saying that the object may not respond to that selector.  Everything works fine at runtime if I just ignore this warning, but warnings are horrible and I don't want to commit any code that has them in there.

I tried declaring the property with `@dynamic` and `@synthesize` at the top of the file and nothing seems to help.  What do I need to do to use the recommended dynamic accessors without generating these warnings?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare the methods in a category on your managed object class:

```
@interface MyManagedObject : NSManagedObject
...
@end

@interface MyManagedObject (PrimitiveAccessors)

- (NSNumberFormatter*)primitiveCurrencyFmt;
- (void)setPrimitiveCurrencyFmt:(NSNumberFormatter*)value;

@end
```

Apple uses this pattern in several places in the documentation to suppress compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0):

With auto-`synthesize` (new since 2010 when this was asked/answered), you can alternatively declare the properties instead. Less code, eliminate typos, etc.

```
@interface MyManagedObject (PrimitiveAccessors)

@property (nonatomic) NSNumberFormatter *primitiveCurrencyFmt;

@end
```

[Apple Example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Listings/DateSectionTitles_APLEvent_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009939-DateSectionTitles_APLEvent_m-DontLinkElementID_6).